# javascript design patterns Revealing Module Pattern how does that work?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, revealing-module-pattern

I'm currently learning javascript and design pattern and i read this piece of code that i don't understand.
Why, and how, can we access the return object??
I understand that's an invoked function in a function; i understand scope (i think i understand scope, but apparently not).. 
And here i'm very confuse about why we can acces what's inside the return object and not the rest..Why the return objects is public??

Can you explain that for me please, or give me a link??

(english is not my first language and it's my first question here, so a apologize if i have broke rules)

the code :

```
// we write the entire object logic as private members and
// expose an anonymous object which maps members we wish to reveal
// to their corresponding public members

var namesCollection = (function() {



 // private members
    var objects = [];

    function addObject(object) {
        objects.push(object);
    }

    function removeObject(object) {
        var index = objects.indexOf(object);
        if (index >= 0) {
            objects.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    function getObjects() {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objects));
    }

    // public members
    return {
        addName: addObject,
        removeName: removeObject,
        getNames: getObjects
    };
})();

namesCollection.addName("Bob");
namesCollection.addName("Alice");
namesCollection.addName("Franck");
// prints ["Bob", "Alice", "Franck"]
console.log(namesCollection.getNames());
namesCollection.removeName("Alice");
// prints ["Bob", "Franck"]
console.log(namesCollection.getNames());
```

The source : https://www.toptal.com/javascript/comprehensive-guide-javascript-design-patterns

Answer (score 0):

I read the link you provided and some more links. This pattern is used to make the readability of the code easier.

In the following code namesCollection has a list, 3 functions and a return statement.

Whenever you call the namesCollection() none of the three function called and objects list is not used but the return statement is running.

return {
        addName: addObject,
        removeName: removeObject,
        getNames: getObjects
    };

Every value is associated with a function

First Line:

**namesCollection.addName("Bob");**

When you are running this line, it is going to the return statement and sees there is a reference given to the addName. Reference leads to addObject() with the value bob. syntax of addObject(object) can be addObject(value) also. Inside the function it is pushing the 'bob' value into the objects list. Objects is now as an element ['Bob'].

Interesting thing is removeName or getNames will not be called because you only called addName.

**namesCollection.addName("Alice");

namesCollection.addName("Franck");**

These two follows the same thing.

Now object is ['Bob','Alice','Frankc']

**console.log(namesCollection.getNames());**

This statement is triggering the getObjects function because of getNames reference in the return statement. it is returning the value of objects, so when you give this inside the console.log() it is printing the list.

if you use console.log() for addName() or removeName() it will not print anything because it is not printing anything. If you want to clearly understand add return objects in both the function and see the output of yourself.

**namesCollection.removeName("Alice");**

Triggering only the removeObject() with the value Alice. Searching for the list name 'Alice' and removing it from the list.

**console.log(namesCollection.getNames());**

Now this statement will give ['Bob','Frankc']

By Using this pattern you don't need to know the actual names of the function, Names of functions in hardcore code will make hard to understand, sometimes it will not make any sense. So Using this simple names are provided such as addName, removeName, getNames() instead of addObject,removeObject,getObjects for better readability and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am too late to answer.

But I have written an tutorial where I explained it

You can have a look and still if you have questions. Please tell me.

https://www.realmelon.com/revealing-module-design-pattern-in-javaScript/